# Can't mount Android device in recovery mode using MTP

Tags: usb, recovery-mode

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S5, (SC-04F), and unfortunately there was some error when installing a new ROM. Now, it only boots into recovery mode.

I am trying to connect by USB so I can copy over a new ROM file, but, the device will not connect to either my Ubuntu or my Windows computer.

The only available connection option in the recovery mode is MTP. I can successfully connect Odin, and I even successfully flashed a new recovery mode from there.

The one thing I can't seem to do is transfer files. Is there any way I can access the disk on my phone in order to transfer some files to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in recovery, connect your phone to PC and you can transfer files to and from phone using ADB Commands, provided it is installed in your machine.

`adb push` and `adb pull` are the commands to send and receive files.

[Instructions to install ADB on Ubuntu](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/328-ubuntu-trusty-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb).

[ADB commands to transfer files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834241/how-to-use-adb-command-to-push-a-file-on-device-without-sd-card).

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the information I needed! I added links to your answer for the exact instructions I used.